# listing custom post type category page

Tags: custom-post-types, archive-template

I've registered custom post type "deals" and its taxonomy "deals-category"
the page site/deals/ runs the archive-deals.php fine
but in page site/deals-category/travel/ runs the archive.php file!
How can i make site/deals-category/travel/ runs the archive-deals.php or other file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to the [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display) to see why this doesn't work. `archive-{$post_type}.php` is only for custom post type archive display, the format for custom taxonomies is `taxonomy-{$taxonomy}.php`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is working now but not the pagination, I'm using wp-pageNavi, the pagination is displayed well, but the title is "page not found" !

Comment: are you modifying the query in the template?

Comment: yes, just post_type, posts_per_page, paged

Comment: use the [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) action to modify queries before they are run, don't do it in the template.

Comment: thanks again, can you give me a detailed example ?

Comment: thanks Milo, I used if(is_post_type_archive('post-type')

Comment: and if(is_tax('post-category')), Thanks very much Milo